# Why different kinds of articles don't change word 'bore' into 'bores' with he-she-it (he bore)

Tags: conjugations

1) **He BORE** the flagon to the altar, which occupied a central position in the court of the priests

2) During the last years of his life he was so thankful to his confreres and **he BORE** his illness in the spirit of faith and with admirable patience

3) **He BORE** inscribed on his face what had to happen in the planet [link](http://www.lletra.net/en/author/eugeni-xammar.pdf)

Comment: This is about different kinds of subjects, not different kinds of articles.

Comment: "Bore" here is the past tense of "to bear"(carry). The present tense would be "He bears the flagon..." or "He bears inscribed on his face..."

Comment: Ya, you don't add an 's' when it's past tense.

Comment: @Jeremy Nottingham thanks a lot
it's a stupid question then)

Comment: @Max The only stupid questions are the ones you don't ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a stupid question, it can be easily made by a learner, in your example

> bore

is the irregular past tense of *bear* (to carry), not to be confused with

> He bores me to death

meaning you find *him* exceedingly *boring*, the past tense of which is *bored*

> He was *bored* at the performance.